# Spring mvc concurrent request processing

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

Can anyone tell how I can process http requests concurrently by Spring mvc?
I've tried to use CompletableFuture or DeferredResult for that, it allows me to process a request in another thread, but next request is still waiting until previous is finished.

What might I miss?

Methods of a controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "simple/async/cf", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<String>> simpleAsyncCf() {
    return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> sleep(1000))
            .thenApplyAsync(v -> ResponseEntity.ok(getRandomString()));
}


@RequestMapping(value = "simple/async/df", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<String>> simpleAsyncDf() {
    DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<String>> result = new DeferredResult<>();
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> sleep(1000))
            .thenApplyAsync(v -> result.setResult(ResponseEntity.ok(getRandomString())));
    return result;
}
```

Comment: request are handled concurrently by default. Why would you need async processing for that. A servlet container handles each request by its own thread (tomcat has 200 request handling threads by default if I recall correctly). Also you need to enable async on the `DispatcherServlet` in your configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But can you tell me how I can make async enable? I tried the @EnableAsync anotation and some parameters from documentation, but I still can't process the second request untill the first is finished.

Comment: If that is really happening something else is wrong as stated requests are handled concurrently already. Also you are trying to use async behavior but if you don't configure a thread pool there is actually a single thread handling those async calls and with that you basically made things worse instead of better. Do you really need this async behavior?

Comment: I've found the mistake It was the use of Postman. It didn't send the second response until getting the first answer, however started counting the request time. Maybe there is something wrong this settings. About configuring the thread pool you are totally right. But I've also noted that spring doesn't use the pool which configured by class which implements AsyncConfigurer for processing callable response. What can be wrong with it?

Comment: Correct as the `AsyncConfigurer` is for something else and not for web related configuration. You will have to override the `configureAsyncSupport` method of the `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` class and register the `TaskExcutor` with the given `AsyncSupportConfigurer`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. Now it works.