# Spring Boot: Architecture: sharing an object among players

Tags: java, spring-boot

Dears,

I'm developing a game and want the Board object to be available to the players playing on it.

So far so good for 1 game at a time, but I've already encountered the following problem:

When calling:

```
@GetMapping({ "/judge/" })
public String judge(Model model,
        @RequestParam(value = "id", required = true, defaultValue = "World") final String hash) {

    ColorsTaken user = colorsTakenRepository.findByHash(hash);

    Board board = BoardController.getInstance().getBoard(gameHash);

    ...

    model.addAttribute("board", board);
    model.addAttribute("user", user);

    return "judge";

}
```

Concurrent calls to judge(...) were interfering and a call of player A to judge(...) rendered the call that player B was doing at the same time...

I "solved" this issue by using a ReentrantLock and locking the call until the judge.jsp was rendered but this is far from an elegant solution...

Furthermore, once there would be different concurrent games the:

```
board.getLock().lock();
```

call will pass through if a different board object are used and making the lock static is an alarm bell that I shouldn't go on with this "solution"...

(There is also the method:

```
@GetMapping({ "/board/" })
public String board(Model model,
        @RequestParam(value = "id", required = true, defaultValue = "World") final String hash) {
```

which renders the board,

if I'd use a static ReentrantLock for these calls all of the players would need to wait until all of the concurrent boards are rendered which isn't a good solution at all...)

(If there are 100 concurrent games 100 * 4 people would need to wait until all of the boards are rendered and this is simply wrong...)

Now, what should I do instead?

The Board object should be shared among the 4 players (any change to it should be available to the other players) but player A of game 1 should not be aware of player F of game 2, but (of course) all changes to game 1 should be available to player B, C and D of game 1...

The code I showed is from a:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {
```

Which architecture should I use to not have to rely on ReentrantLocks?

Best regards and thanks,

S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently concurrent calls to @Controller methods are handled in different threads:

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42389974/spring-mvc-concurrent-request-processing#comment71928886_42389974)...

Digging deeper the reason why the judge(...) calls interfered was because they rendered this:

```
Green: ${board.greenName}: ${board.getPlayerString(0, user)}<br /> <br /> 
Blue: ${board.blueName}: ${board.getPlayerString(1, user)}<br /> <br /> 
Red: ${board.redName}: ${board.getPlayerString(2, user)}<br />  <br /> 
Yellow: ${board.yellowName}: ${board.getPlayerString(3, user)}<br /> <br />
```

And the "greenName", "blueName", ... where changed in the common Board object, if calls would be made with different Board objects these calls would be handled by different threads and modifying different board objects (if these calls originated from players from different boards...)

Answer (score 0):

Shared data should be placed in database, like mysql and postgresql, instead of in application memory.